# PostgreSQL return multiple rows with DISTINCT though only latest date per second column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Lets says I have the following database table (date truncated for example only, two 'id_' preix columns join with other tables)...

```
+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+

| id_table1 | id_tab2 | date | description        | price |

+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+

| 1         | 11      | 2014 | man-eating-waffles | 1.46  |

+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+

| 2         | 22      | 2014 | Flying Shoes       | 8.99  |

+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+

| 3         | 44      | 2015 | Flying Shoes       | 12.99 |
+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+
```

...and I have a query like the following...

```
SELECT id, date, description FROM inventory ORDER BY date ASC;
```

How do I `SELECT` all the descriptions, but only once each while simultaneously only the *latest* year for that description? So I need the database query to return the first and last row from the sample data above; the second it not returned because the last row has a later date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgres has something called `distinct on`.  This is usually more efficient than using window functions.  So, an alternative method would be:

```
SELECT distinct on (description) id, date, description
FROM inventory
ORDER BY description, date desc;
```

Comment: Got things ironed out and was able to successfully test this and it seems to work just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `row_number` [`window function`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html) should do the trick:

```
SELECT  id, date, description 
FROM    (SELECT id, date, description, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY description 
                                   ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
         FROM   inventory) t
WHERE    rn = 1
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Comment: Up-voted, thanks. Seems to work though a little convoluted, what is the `t` for on the fifth line?

Comment: @John it's a table alias for the subquery. Postgres mandates them.

Comment: Okay, I never do aliases without `AS`, makes it easier to speed past those tidbits.